# MySQL obtener cliente con más productos en un pedido (3 tablas)

Tags: mysql

Necesito sacar el cliente (id_cliente) que tiene el pedido (id_pedido) con más productos (id_producto) adquiridos en el mismo. Hasta ahora he conseguido sacar el pedido con más unidades, pero ¿cómo puedo obtener el id del cliente?

3 tablas
clientes (id_cliente PK...)
pedidos (id_pedido PK, id_cliente FK...)
resumenpedidos (id_pedido FK, id_producto)

Este es mi código hasta ahora...

```
SELECT MAX(cantidad)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(r.id_pedido) AS cantidad
    FROM resumenpedidos r 
    GROUP BY r.id_pedido) AS results;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos JOIN (
    SELECT id_pedido,
      COUNT(DISTINCT id_producto) n_productos_diferentes
      FROM resumenpedidos
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_producto)=(
        SELECT MAX(n_productos_diferentes)
          FROM (
            SELECT id_pedido,
              COUNT(DISTINCT id_producto) n_productos_diferentes
              FROM resumenpedidos
              GROUP BY 1  
          ) c1  
      )  
  ) c2 USING(id_pedido)
  JOIN clientes USING(id_cliente);
```

Te ha faltado identificar ese pedido y, de éste, obtener el `id_cliente`. Échale un vistazo a mi propuesta y, si tienes cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios.